# Batch file script concatenate strings

Tags: batch-file, concatenation

I want to concatenate strings in a batch file because I need to parameterize in the batch file (.bat) to use paths frequently. So instead of writing:

```
ren "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\filename.ext.tmp" "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\filename.ext"
del "C:\Folder\Sub Folder\filename.ext.tmp"
```

I would like to write something like

```
set pathString="C:\Folder\Sub Folder\"
ren pathString+"filename.ext.tmp" pathString+"filename.ext"
del pathString+"filename.ext.tmp"
```

Is this somehow doable? If so how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example the command should be:

```bat
Set "pathString=C:\Folder\Sub Folder"
Ren "%pathString%\filename.ext.tmp" "filename.ext"
```

There's no path needed for the rename destination because it hasn't changed, *(therefore no need to prefix it with `%pathString%`)*. Then there's no need to delete the file you've just renamed because it no longer exists after being renamed.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic batch variable usage, just remember to use the quotes correctly:

```
set pathString=C:\Folder\Sub Folder
ren "%pathString%\filename.ext.tmp" "%pathString%\filename.ext"
del "%pathString%\filename.ext.tmp"
```

That being said, your example code does not make a lot of sense because

- you are trying to delete a file that will not exist because you rename it to something else?

or

- you think you need to rename the file before deleting it?

Renaming before deletion only makes sense if you are trying to delete a locked file and deletion failure is acceptable. Doing that would look something like this:

```
@echo off

REM Set up some things for this example:
md "%temp%\batchtest"
echo.blah blah > "%temp%\batchtest\filename.ext"

REM Actual code:

set pathString=%temp%\batchtest
ren "%pathString%\filename.ext" "filename.ext.del"
del "%pathString%\filename.ext.del"
```